# How can I read custom action's executable output in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, custom-action

I'm making MSI installer in WiX. During installation I want to run an executable from a [custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm) and get its standard output (not the return code) for later use during installation (with [`Property`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_property.htm) element, supposedly).

How can I achieve it in WiX (3.5)?

Comment: Do you mean your custom actions calls some EXE which writes to console, and you'd like to grab that output?

Comment: Yan, yes, that's what I meant. Question edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this code for a similar task (its a C# DTF custom action):

```
// your process data
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
   CreateNoWindow = true,
   LoadUserProfile = true,
   UseShellExecute = false,
   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
   StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
   ...
};

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processInfo;
process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
  {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) && session != null)
     {
         // HERE GOES THE TRICK!
         Record record = new Record(1);
         record.SetString(1, e.Data);
         session.Message(InstallMessage.ActionData, record);
      }
  };

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();

if (process.ExitCode != 0) {
   throw new Exception("Execution failed (" + processInfo.FileName + " " + processInfo.Arguments + "). Code: " + process.ExitCode);
}

process.Close();
```

Comment: So I should create a custom action which executes the executable and grabs its console output. Looks like a good start, but how I can access the output during the installation process (in a property or a variable)? There's no UI in my case (silent installation), so I'm not going to display the grabbed output but use it for further processing eg. for a parameter in a condition or another cusom action. These are my first steps in WiX, so sorry for my importunity.

Comment: The block marked //here goes the trick  will probably do some parsing of string and then do something like session["SOMEPROPERTY"] = someParsedString

Comment: But I really don't reccomend this approach even if it is possible.  This will increase installer fragility.

Answer (score 4):

This is called "screen scraping" and while it's technically possible to create the infrastructure to run an EXE out of process, scrape it's output and then marshal the data back into the MSI context, it'll never be a robust solution.

A better solution would be to understand what the EXE does and how it does it. Then write a C# o C++ custom action that runs in process with access to the MSI handle so that you can do the work and set the properties you need to set.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, but it's not really a solution to my problem. The console application is shipped by a third party and I just HAVE to use it and rely on its output. Reverse engineering and rewriting existing application doesn't seem that robust.

Comment: It's very robust. It just isn't very *EASY*.  You are creating a pattern that takes a dependency on a third party EXE and you are injecting it into your installer.  If it ever fails (it will) they won't blame the third party dependency, they will blame your installer.

Comment: +1, @Chris, thanks for your criticism. I see your point and I agree it might be dangerous if you rely on the third party EXE. But do you think it is appropriate if it's your own utility? Let's say you have been using that utility for quite some time, and it was fully covered by tests and proved it works stable enough. Isn't it better to just grab its output instead of adjusting to the custom action? It might mean the duplication of the code you already have, and introducing new issues as a result of copying/pasting...

Comment: I'd say if it's your own utility then the code should be factored out into an EXE and DLL.  The functions / methods exposed by the DLL  could then be consumed by your custom action.  Now you have a CA client and an EXE client but the core logic isn't duplicated.  This then gives you programatic access to the logic with full error handling and logging.  No code duplication is needed.

Comment: I have a similar problem except my executable returns a string how do I capture it in a wix variable?